# Given $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N \in \mathbb{R}$, Prove: $f(x)= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}|x-y_i|^2$ gets a minimum, and find it.

Tags: calculus

I'd love your help with this following problem:

Given $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N \in \mathbb{R}$, I need to prove that  $f(x)= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N}|x-y_i|^2$ gets a minimum, and to find it.

I don't know really how to solve it,

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I changed "a minima" to "a minimum".  The former is plural; the latter is singular.  "This minimum is...." or "These minima are...."  Lots of students get confused about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use calculus, or not. Expand the squares. We get
$$f(x)=Nx^2-2x\sum_{i=1}^N y_i+\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2.$$
This is a quadratic in $x$, and the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive. So the curve $y=f(x)$ is an upward facing parabola.

Thus $f(x)$ has a minimum, where the parabola is lowest, and it can be found in the usual calculus way.

But I would like to do it another way. Multiply $f(x)$ by $N$.
We get
$$Nf(x)=N^2x^2-2xN\sum y_i + N\sum y_i^2.$$
Complete the square. We get 
$$Nf(x)=\left(Nx-\sum y_i\right)^2+N\sum y_i^2-\left(\sum y_i\right)^2.$$
Then $Nf(x)$ is obviously minimized when $Nx-\sum y_i=0$, that is, when 
$$x=\frac{\sum y_i}{N},$$
since $\left(Nx-\sum y_i\right)^2$ is always $\ge 0$.
The minimum value of $Nf(x)$ is therefore $N\sum y_i^2-\left(\sum y_i\right)^2$. It follows that the minimum value of $f(x)$ is equal to
$$\sum y_i^2-\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum y_i\right)^2.$$

**Remark:** This is not just an "exercise": it has great practical importance, in Statistics and elsewhere.  I will change the notation to the one the problem *should* have used, and write $x_i$ instead of $y_i$. So we have $N$ data points (numbers) $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$, and would like to find the value of $x$ which is in some sense nearest to our collection of data points, which best fits them. For technical reasons, we want to minimize the sum of the *squares* of the deviations from $x$ to the $x_i$, the sum of the squares of the "errors."
So we are minimizing
$$\sum_{i=1}^N(x-x_i)^2.$$
The minimum value is reached, as we saw, when $x=\frac{\sum x_i}{N}$. This is the average (mean) of the $x_i$.
Actually, we usually want to minimize $\frac{f(x)}{N}$. By our calculation, the minimum value of this is 
$$\frac{\sum x_i^2}{N}-\left(\frac{\sum x_i}{N}\right)^2,$$
which is usually called the *variance* of the collection of  data points $x_i$. The variance in a sense measures how far, on average, the $x_i$ depart from the mean.

Comment: Interesting.. Even though I wanted calculus solution, it was nice to read. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jozef: For calculus, the differentiation is trivial. Don't let the absolute values confuse you, the terms are just $(x-y_i)^2$, with derivatives $2(x-y_i)$.  Add up, set equal to $0$. We get $x=(\sum y_i)/N$. Have min there because of the geometry.   For min value, just substitute. I knew you wanted a calculus solution, and sort of gave one. After the first expansion, I wrote that the thing could be minimized in the usual calculus way.  Just a fancied up version of minimize $3x^2-2x+7$.  If we are going to use calculus, the expand step is unnecessary, we can differentiate immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For what $x$ does $f'(x)=0$?

Comment: I got confused, Do you consider $f$ a function form $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes: $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\quad x \longmapsto \sum (x-y_i)^2$

Comment: O.k,  $f'(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{N}2|x-y_i|$, so only if $y_i$ are all equal and $y_i=x$ , $f'(x)=0$, right?

Comment: No $f'(x) = 2\left( Nx - \sum y_i \right)$, so $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = \frac{1}{N}\sum y_i$.

Comment: O.k, What should i do in order to see if it is minimum or not?

Comment: $f''(x) = 2N > 0$ so it is a minimum.